# Excel Hlookup with iferror

Tags: excel

I have a range of values that I am trying to compare against another range of values using an IFERROR and also a HLOOKUP, if the value is found it will return the value in the below row.

My formula (below) works for the first two values in range one against range two but I can't seem to get it working for the following values (9 in total)

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(LookUp!$B$3,'Data Load-Monthly IMS'!$B$2:$L$11091,ROWS($B$2:$B3),FALSE),(HLOOKUP(LookUp!$B$4,'Data Load-Monthly IMS'!$B$2:$L$11091,ROWS($B$2:$B3),FALSE)))
```

So my nine values in my range one to compare would be LookUp!$B$3 down as far as LookUp!$B$11, but I can't seem to get it to work if I add a third condition to my above code - but the two arguments above do work, I just can't add another. (I hope thats clear)

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than 9 `HLOOKUPs` you can use MATCH function to check whether all 9 B4:B11 values exist in row 2 and retrieve the first match

`=INDEX('Data Load-Monthly IMS'!$B3:$L3,MATCH(INDEX(LookUp!$B$4:$B$11,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER( MATCH(LookUp!$B$4:$B$11,'Data Load-Monthly IMS'!$B$2:$L$2,0)),0),0)),'Data Load-Monthly IMS'!$B$2:$L$2,0))`

Drag formula down and you get row 4 result etc.

You might be able to simplify formula depending on circumstances - is it possible for more than one B4:B11 value to match? What sort of data are you retrieving, is it text or numeric?

**Additional info**

Given your comments it will be easier to use `SUMIF`, assuming criteria in G3:G11 try this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF('Data Load-Monthly IMS'!$B$2:$L$2,LookUp!$G$3:$G$11,'Data Load-Monthly IMS'!$B3:$L3))`

`SUMIF` creates an array of 9 totals (the number of entries in ookUp!$G$3:$G$11) and then SUMPRODUCT is used to sum those and get your final result

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately your formula does not seem to work for me, I am getting an '#N/A' error, i'm trying to play around with it current but i'm not having much lucky.


Just to clarify, the 9 values I need to look up (LookUp!$G$3:$G$11) are text values (col headings), Im trying to see whether any of those 9 values exist in a different worksheet called 'Data Load-Monthly IMS' cells ranging from $B$2:$L$2 and if a match is found I need the value in the third row (B3) to be returned. The values in B3,B4,B5 etc down along will be numeric values - I hope thats clear.

Comment: What if there are two matches, which takes precedence, the first match from G3:G11..or the first match in B2:L2?

Comment: There will only ever be one match, so imagine G3:G11 is like Jan 2010,Jan 2011, Jan 2012 etc... and B2:L2 is like Jan 2010, Feb 2010, Mar 2010, so each year the data in B2:L2 will be overwritten to become Jan 2011.

Comment: If there's only going to be one match, and you have numeric data then it will be easier to use SUMIF, I updated my answer to that effect......